# Installing Bouncy Castle on Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, cryptography, bouncycastle

*I am pretty new to Mac OS, or Bouncy Castle/Encryption at all*, hence I am following the guide [here](http://www.itcsolutions.eu/2011/08/22/how-to-use-bouncy-castle-cryptographic-api-in-netbeans-or-eclipse-for-java-jse-projects/) and downloaded the [PGP-JDK1.5-1.7](http://www.bouncycastle.org/download/bcpg-jdk15on-151.jar) version of [Bouncy Castle jar](http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html).

I issued the below command to see where Java is installed:

```
bash-3.2$ sudo find / -name "*.security"
Password: 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/MacOS/itms/java/lib/security/java.security
find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/security/java.security
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/java.security
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/java.security
/Users/fn.lastname/code/vault/security_java_jars_Aug11/java.security
```

I then added **security.provider.11=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider** to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/java.security and also added the bouncy castle jar to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext

The changed java.security content is as below:

```
security.provider.1=sun.security.provider.Sun
security.provider.2=sun.security.rsa.SunRsaSign
security.provider.3=sun.security.ec.SunEC
security.provider.4=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider
security.provider.5=com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE
security.provider.6=sun.security.jgss.SunProvider
security.provider.7=com.sun.security.sasl.Provider
security.provider.8=org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI
security.provider.9=sun.security.smartcardio.SunPCSC
security.provider.10=apple.security.AppleProvider
security.provider.11=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
```

I went to eclipse(STS) and executed the [program here](https://github.com/Languafe/Beginning-Cryptography-with-Java/blob/master/src/chapter1/SimpleProviderTest.java) to see if the Bouncy Castle is successfully installed. It just returned "BC provider not installed".

I tried the same on the location at **/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/java.security**

Again ran the program with out any success. I also tried googling other sites, alas much help. Seems to have good support for Windows, but for mac I need help even to find if I am at the right Java version.

Could any of you please let me know where I could sense issues? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks @Rachael. I noted that I had issues with inappropriate jar file. I had set bcprov-jdk15on-151.jar, bcprov-ext-jdk15on-151.jar, bcpg-jdk15on-151.jar into classpath but did removed the one from ext location. I did retain the changes to java.security. I was not able to try out with each of the jar files into ext one-by-one to see which was important, but to me bcprov-jdk15on-151.jar seemed to be the most important.

Comment: Here's [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35069667/4224769) to a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Bouncy Castle is a set of libraries. There is the core library with the provider, called `jcprov-*`. To use (a subset of) the Bouncy Castle core cryptography you need to install the provider using the signed `.jar`. This `.jar` is the *only* one containing the provider.

The `bcpkix` (ANSI X standards PKI), `bcpg` (PGP) and `bcmail` (SMIME/CMS/PKCS#7) libraries are standalone libraries that provide specific functionality on top of JCE. You may not even have to install the provider for a lot of the functionality. They do not contain the provider themselves.

So you can use the `.jar` directly, and if required, download the `.jar` containing the provider and put it in your classpath...

Comment: Anything missing from my answer?

Answer (score -1):

I remember having to run a key tool command...

Found it here:

[How Do You Configure BouncyCastle For Mac OSX Maverick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21893754/how-do-you-configure-bouncycastle-for-mac-osx-maverick)

Comment: That command simply runs `keytool` with the BC provider without installing it.

Comment: Try not to use too popular language on SO, this is a Q/A site, not youtube.